# screen is dimmed when running VLC (on desktop, not battery related!)

Tags: windows, windows-xp, lcd, sp3

When I play movies in VLC, the screen is dimmed. Most of the Google search results are related to battery/power management in laptops, or to Ubuntu.

My desktop computer doesn't have battery, it's always connected to the computer.

- It is windows XP.
- The screen is LCD
- The monitor driver is "plug and play monitor"
- I’ve recently upgraded to SP3.

I don’t find dimming options at "control panel > power"
there’s no specific driver to my monitor that controls dimming.

How can I stop the screen from dimming?

Comment: is it really dimmed or just darkened? have you tried to use a different output method in vlc? maybe there's a problem with directshow

Comment: what's the difference between DIMMED and DARKENED?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible hints that I can see are :

1. An installed "experience optimizing" software product
2. The monitor has an 'intelligent' brightness control, which might be disabled from its own menu.
3. Power configuration was by error set to laptop.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in Windows 10:

I have two monitors. I launch VLC video in full screen on one of monitors, it dims, using <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + arrow I move video to another monitor and back to the initial monitor - it doesn't dim anymore.